# Scp copies data to server from GitLab and exit with code 1: No such file or directory

Tags: gitlab-ci, scp

I have my script on GitLab, and I would like to copy my scripts to my server in `deploy` pipeline. I create env variables with my `USER_IP` and `USER_PASS` for sshpass comand. This is the output of my pipeline:

```
$ sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r project root@${USER_IP}:/opt
Warning: Permanently added '1.2.3.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The problem is, the pipeline faild, but data has been copied to server. So why The job failed with exit code 1 and message `root@: No such file or directory`?

Is there better way how to deploy data to server from GitLab?

Comment: Is `USER_IP` correctly defined? `echo $USER_IP` to check it, for example.

Comment: Yes it is. The data are copied to the server.

Comment: Could there be a space at the start of USER_IP? That would ask to copy 2 things to the destination, and explain the behavior!

Comment: It looks like there was more than an address in `USER_IP`. I reiplace 'USER_IP' with IP address again and now it's work. Thank you.